# How i declare the 'prebuild' script in package.json, to run only in the gitlab pipeline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json

Hi i need to have some `lint & tests` **scripts**, executed just before the `yarn build`, in the **gitlab pipeline**.

The scripts in `package.json` are simple:
`prebuild: CI=true npm test && npm run lint,`
`build: react-scripts build`

The `prebuild` script runs every time i run the `yarn build`, but i need to distinguish when it runs locally from when it runs in the CI/CD.

Is there a flag or a parameter that could do that, or a doc for the package.json ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use environment variables for that (set on your CI/CD environment, unset on local environment). You could also define specific scripts for CI/CD

Comment: thanks it make sense.
But should i need a condition into the script, like : `"prebuild": "CI=true NODE_ENV=production && npm test"`

Comment: Yes that could totally do the trick

Comment: Thanks. 
Actually what i mean is that, the `prebuild` script runs automatically whenever we execute `yarn build`. 
So a condition may filter when the `prebuild`  runs or not.

Comment: I actually don't know about that hook

Comment: Maybe better to add "npm test" and "npm run lint" directly in your pipeline before running build?

Comment: Sounds a  good idea @Ariel.